# Conditionally show / hide b-table column based on store getters

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to show / hide table column '**first_name**' based on if user **isAdmin** or not.

This is my table:

```
<b-table
      striped
      hover
      small
      stacked="sm"
      selectable
      select-mode="single"
      show-empty
      :items="allProducts"
      :fields="productsFieldsForBTable"
      :busy="isLoading"
      primary-key="id"
    >
      <template slot="actions" slot-scope="data">
        <select v-model="data.selected">
          <option v-for="user in users" :key="user.id" :value="user.id">{{user.first_name}}</option>
        </select>
      </template>
    </b-table>
```

This is **productsFieldsForBTable** in store getters.

```
productsFieldsForBTable: () => {
      return [ 
        {
          key: 'product_name',
          sortable: true,
        },
        {
          key: 'buying_price',
          sortable: true,
        },
        {
          key: 'notes',
          sortable: true,
        },
        {

          key: 'first_name',
          label: 'User',
          sortable: true,
        },
        // A virtual column for additional action buttons
        { key: 'actions', label: 'Actions' }
      ]
    }
```

store getters have isAdmin flag that will be used to hide / show column

I am not sure what syntax to use and where to check conditions? (in b-table tag or in computed?)

Updated -

How do I access isAdmin value from store itself? its in getters as shown below:

getters: {
        isAdmin: (state, getters) => { return getters.isLoggedIn && state.user.role === 'Admin' }, ....

```
if(getter.isAdmin){ // how to access getters' isAdmin here? // this.$store.getters.isAdmin is not working here.

        fields.push({

          key: 'first_name',
          label: 'User',
          sortable: true
        })
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use mapGetters from Vuex and map `productFieldsForBTable` as computed property to your component. Then in your getter instead of returning an array in line do something like this:

```
    productsFieldsForBTable: (state, getters) => {
      var fields = [ 
        {
          key: 'product_name',
          sortable: true,
        },
        {
          key: 'buying_price',
          sortable: true,
        },
        {
          key: 'notes',
          sortable: true,
        },
        {

          key: 'first_name',
          label: 'User',
          sortable: true,
        },
        // A virtual column for additional action buttons
        { key: 'actions', label: 'Actions' }
      ]

      if(getters.isAdmin){
         fields.push({
           key: 'admin_field',
           sortable: true,
         })
      }

      return fields
    }
```

If you didn't want the admin fields at the end of the table you could always the `splice` function instead of `push`. Something like below would put the admin item before the actions:

```
var index = 4 // index you want to insert the new column at
fields.splice(index, 0, { key: 'admin_field', sortable: true })
```

Comment: thanks. I tried the same and its almost there now. how do I access the isAdmin value from getters in store within store itself ? (i've update questoin for the same)

Comment: I edited my response, you need to change your function to accept the state and getters param. Also in your example code you posted in the update you are using 'getter' instead of 'getters'. But before that you need to make sure the param is in your productsFieldsForBTable function